# Supply function parameters as text

Tags: r, function

For a loop i need some algorithm that will iteratively supply a list of parameters in a from of string to a function.

The minimal example may be as follows:

```
my_func <- function(x, a=0, b=0){
            print(x)
            if(a == 0){
              return('a is zero')
              } else {
                print(paste0(a, ' and ', b))
                }
}
```

It should work like this:

```
abc(10, a=5, b=3)
[1] 10
[1] "5 and 3"
```

However, i cannot find a way for function to work correctly with string input for all parameters `abc(10, paste0('a=5, b=3'))`, which takes this string as an input for first argument:

```
[1] 10
[1] "a=5, b=3 and 0"
```

If there are some other options to supply to a function a list of arguments (other than in a form of a string), you are welcome!

Comment: You might take a look at the `purrr::invoke` family of functions. They let you supply lists of arguments to one or more functions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `purrr::invoke_map`, which takes a combination of a list of functions and a list of function arguments. In this case, you only need one function, but you can use a list of lists of arguments `x`, `a`, and `b`.

Note in your function: you've got 3 statements that deal with creating some output. Two of these are `print` calls and one is `return`. I changed the `return` to a `print` thinking it may have been a mistake, but feel free to disregard if that's not the case.

Using a set of dummy arguments, I'm calling `invoke_map` and saving it to the variable `out`, which is a list of the same length as the input list. I saved it only because otherwise you have things printing out twice: once when calling the `print`s in the function, and one as the last line is being returned.

```r
library(purrr)

my_func <- function(x, a=0, b=0){
  print(x)
  if(a == 0){
    # return('a is zero')
    print("a is zero")
  } else {
    print(paste0(a, ' and ', b))
  }
}

params <- list(
  list(x = 10, a = 5, b = 2),
  list(x = 3, a = 11, b = 1),
  list(x = 5, a = 0, b = 9)
)

out <- invoke_map(my_func, params)
#> [1] 10
#> [1] "5 and 2"
#> [1] 3
#> [1] "11 and 1"
#> [1] 5
#> [1] "a is zero"
```

<sup>Created on 2019-01-23 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Here is an attempt: You can use base regex functions.

```
  my_func1<-function(x, string){

  a<-as.numeric(sapply(stringr::str_extract_all(string,"\\d"),"[")[1])
  b<-as.numeric(sapply(stringr::str_extract_all(string,"\\d"),"[")[2])

  print(x)
  if(a == 0){
    return('a is zero')
  } else {
   print(paste0(a," and ", b))
  }
}

my_func1(x=10,"a=5,b=5")
#[1] 10
#[1] "5 and 5"
```